# fill kendo combo box parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a kendo combobox Clients, and I fill his content with

```
.DataSource(
                source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetAllClientsJSONCombo", "CrmCProfile"); });
                })
```

Now, I have another kendo combobox ContactsClient, but I need pass the Id of the selected client in first combobox, like this:

```
.DataSource(source =>
           {
               source.Read(read =>
               {
                   read.Action("GetAllContactsClientJSONCombo", "CrmCProfile", new object { Id_Cliente = (????????)});
               })
              .ServerFiltering(false);
           })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine if you dont write `new object` just specify the word `new`

```
.DataSource(source =>
    {
         source.Read(read =>
         {
             read.Action("GetAllContactsClientJSONCombo", "CrmCProfile", new { Id_Cliente = Model.Value});
         })
        .ServerFiltering(false);
    })
```

OR

```
.DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetAllContactsClientJSONCombo", "CrmCProfile").Data("yourParameters");
        })
       .ServerFiltering(false);
    })


<script>
function yourParameters(){
    return {"Id_Cliente": yourParameterValue};
}
</script>
```

And make sure that on the server side, the name of the parameter (i.e, `Id_Cliente`) is same.

```
public JsonResult GetAllContactsClientJSONCombo(string Id_Cliente){
    //your logic here
}
```

Comment: I need that the Id_Cliente value be readed from another combo_box, combo_box Clientes. This value, selected in combo_box Clientes is the value that I want pass to Action that return the list of contacts of a given client. Suggest???

Comment: [Cascading Drop Down](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist.html)